# For in In lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like that, in a nutshell...

```
house = ['yes', 'no','maybe']

x = range(3)

for x in house
  print[x]
```

---

I want to loop over a list but I got 'type error: list indices must be integers not Tags.' How can I achieve this ?

Comment: That code has a syntax error, some dead code and propably doesn't produce the output you want, but it doesn't give a type error, much less one with such a weird message.

Comment: This code doesnt produce any error in py 2.6. It prints ['yes']...etc

Comment: @joaquin a missing colon after house in the for loop will generate the syntax error.

Comment: @user496713, Ah! thanks. My brain wrote the colon automatically

Answer (score 7):

If you want to iterate over a list, you don't need an index at all:

```
for x in house:
  print x # prints every house
```

If you want an index, you can use different approaches:

```
# generate indexes on the fly
for i, a_house in enumerate(house):
  print i, a_house # prints 0 yes, 1 no, 2 maybe

# access by index
# you may change boundaries or reverse order, e.g. try range(2, -1 , -1)
for i in range(3): 
  print house[i]
```

Comment: You can also iterate through a list backwards using slices (`for i in house[::-1]: print i`) or using the `reversed` builtin (`for i in reversed(house): print i`).

Answer (score 3):

Just think on plain english:

```
for item in house:
    print item
```

that is one of python powers.

Answer (score 2):

what you want is something more like this:

```
house = ['yes', 'no', 'maybe']
for x in range(3):
    print house[x]
```

Comment: Virtual -1: It works, but shows you don't know much about Python - at least not about iteration in Python (it's `for x in house: print x`, period).

Comment: I don't think this answer must have negatve rating, but on SO it is often not enough to post a correct piece of code. Often it is expected to tell why the question asks for a wrong thing, and how to do the right thing achieving the same ends.

Comment: Real +1: because it shows how to iterate with an index and use it -- even if there are more idiomatic [usually better] Python approaches (as `enumerate`). Although if this approach *is* used, should likely be `for x in range(len(house)):` to avoid having the hard-coded const.

Comment: @pynator Misplaced comment? ;-)

Comment: @pynator, please watch the tone. There's no need to be insulting or call names.

Answer (score 1):

No range need...

for item in house:
   print item